# Replace dropdown multiselect content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I have two dropdown multiselect boxes that have html content populated depending on the call from the dataset and other dropdowns.

For example:

> 1st dropdown: All Animals, Bird, Dog.
>
> 2nd dropdown: All Traits, Talons, Beak, Paw, Fur.

In order to sort the second dropdown I've been `.remove()`ing the children it's `ul` class and `.append()`ing new html children along with their values. Like so

```
$.each(data, initDataSet);

function initDataSet(key, value) {

   if (value !== null && typeof value === "object") {
      $('.dropdown-content-traits').append("<li href='#' class='traitDropDownItem dropDownGeneral'>"+ value.name +"</li>");
   }
}
```

The problem is now I want to add multiselect to the dropdown and I'm having trouble adding a 'selected' class to each list item because the content is being sorted everytime the dropdown is clicked on.

Without changing the html tags to: `<select>` and `<option>` what's a more efficient way to manage the dropdown content?